# Blazor App on first load different from subsequent loads

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, blazor

So this is my first blazor app and the goal of it is to create a lobby system where player can join games on game keys and check how much money they have, send money to other players in the "game", etc. I started off with the home page and on the running from Visual Studio it looks like this [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnuYr.png).

On start new game, it is supposed to redirect to another page which was not working.
I then did further testing and had the page (/lobby), redirect back to the index or home page (/) and manually entered the url (localhost/lobby). That directed me to the site as expected and when I clicked the button to take me back to the index, it also ended up working, however the page now loads like this [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id9sL.png).

Below is the code in the index or home page.

```html
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@using MonopolyCash.Data


<style>
.container {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>

<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="center">
            <h1>Welcome to Monopoly Cash Online</h1>
            <p>Enter your name: <input @bind-value="name" @bind-value:event="oninput"/></p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="create">Start New Game</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="create">Join a Game</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

@code {
    private string name { get; set; } = "";
    private void create()
    {
        String key = new Helper().generateKey();
        ClientObject co = new ClientObject("host", key, name, 1500);
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/lobby");
    }
}
```

And here is the code in the lobby page. (Currently mostly placeholder from the provided template).

```html
@page "/lobby"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/");

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Could you clarify your problem or question?

Comment: The main problem is the difference in the pictures. When I first run my program in visual studio, the page loads fine but no event handlers work, but when I manually redirect myself to the page by the URL, the page view looks like the second picture, but the event handlers work.

Comment: It's unusual to have a body tag, inside a component's HTML. However, the logic looks fine. My guess is, that the HTML structure is not 100% recognized by the browser.  Could you add the index.html and App.razor and, if used, your layout pages?

Comment: Remove the `body` tag, your index page should have that already and you can't have more than one. That, and/or other errors might be the reason for the strange behavior (events not working is characteristic of an exception, look for them in the console); the style tag not being parsed is characteristic of malformed HTML.